# Change keyboard shortcut in sublime text 2

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

How do i change the current keys for selecting all with the multiple cursor to CMD + G?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts are referrred to as key bindings in Sublime Text 2. There is documentation [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) and [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings) that will show you how to manipulate them. Click "Preferences" > "Default Key Bindings" to view them. Copy and paste the ones you want to edit into "Preferences" > "User Key Bindings"

e.g.

```
 <binding key="cmd+t,u" command="upperCase"/>
```

As noted in the comments, the config is now in json format for newer Sublime Text.

e.g.

```
    { "keys": ["cmd+t,u"], "command": "snake_case" }
```

Comment: Just a heads up, that link is outdated. Here is an updated one. [link](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) Only important because configs are json now rather than XML.