# custom keybinding on find and Reg replace in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Am thinking whether it's achievable to make shortcut key-bindings on user 
sublime key-map, so that one-key-triggered "find reg expression and replace-all" 
if can assign custom keybinding will save a lot of work.

For example can be applied to make below answer into shortcut: 
[Sublime Text 2: How to delete blank/empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008986/sublime-text-2-how-to-delete-blank-empty-lines)

Thanks to Joyas's answer, Below is the usage that could achieve the above task.

1.install RegReplace plugin for sublime 2/3

2.configure user reg replace function

```
      {
            "replacements": {
                "remove_blank_lines": {
                    "find" : "(^\n)",
                "replace": "",
                "greedy_replace": true
               }
            }
     }
```

3.configure key bindings

```
  {
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"],
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {"replacements": ["remove_blank_lines"]}
  }
```

4. go to font-end press shortcut and it works so good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925302/change-keyboard-shortcut-in-sublime-text-2) about custom shortcut in sublime text.

In order to change the default shortcut for find and replace, you just have to edit de the line

> { "keys": ["super+shift+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args":
>   {"panel": "find_in_files"} }

in you preferences.

Furthermore, if you want to create a keybinding in order to "find and replace" a specific sequence of character, it seems that there is the plugin [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace) to do so.

Comment: thanks joyas, i'd like to keybind "find and replace" to a specific sequence of characters.  I've installed the 'RegReplace" and it works like charm.